(Blow-up) Resolution of singularities and arithmetic genus
Suppose $X$ is a $k=\overline{k}$-variety with a node at a closed point $p$. Let $\tilde{X}$ be the blow-up of $X$ at $p$.
In Exercise 28.3.E, Vakil asks to show that there is an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{O}_X\to\beta_*O_{\tilde{X}}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to 0$, and his hint is to use faithfully flatness. However, I can't even figure out what the map $\beta_*O_{\tilde{X}}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is.
In Exercise 28.3.F, he supposes further that $X$ is a pure-dimensional reduced projective curve, and asks us to show that $p_a(X) = p_a(\tilde{X}) + 1$ (where $p_a$ denotes the arithmetic genus). Using $p_a(X)=1-\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and the additivity of the Euler characteristic, I think I reduced the problem to show that $\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_{X,p})=1$.
This number $\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_{X,p})$ is supposed to depend on the type of singularity at $p$ and to be always positive, according to some remarks Vakil does just after the exercise. I also imagine it should be $0$ if the point $p$ is regular. However, I have no idea how to calculate this value.
How can I relate the type of singularity at a point $p$ (defined in terms of completions of local rings) with the evaluation of the Euler characteristic of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$? How can I make sense of the exact sequence of Exercise 28.3.E?

$\mathcal{O}{X, p}$ is not the right cokerel here. You want the skyscraper sheaf at $p$, valued at $k$. ($\dim_k \mathcal{O}{X, p} = \infty$ in general.)
